VirtualAlloc error 1314
On two seemingly similar Windows 10 22H2 machines, an application acts differently: on one it works and reports that it is able to use VirtualAlloc() to allocate large pages, on the other it throws error 1314 and falls back to regular pages. On both it runs under the elevated command prompt.
The first thing I checked was the group policy setting "Lock pages in memory". On the 1st machine where the app works it only had the current user added. On the 2nd one where it fails it also had Administrator. For giggles, I removed Administrator, and now the policies are the same between the machines, but the app still fails with the same error.
What should be the next troubleshooting steps?

It's worth comparing all the hardware specs between the two.  (Way back) I've seen Dell laptops with different hardware arrive in the same order - in that case, the specific video chipset apparently changed and we happened to have the bulk order that included the crossover, and the boot screens came up at different resolutions.  If they have different hardware (thinking RAM here), you'd have different hardware drivers - it's conceivable that it could affect a low-level command like that, perhaps as a driver bug.

To clarify, I'm suggesting to compare the actual hardware specs - not the "as configured in the order" spec, but what the OS actually sees for each device & chipset, etc).  That Dell order was twenty-some of a single spec'd laptop - so they were 'identical' in as far as both the PO and Dell fulfillment was concerned.  The difference was down at the nuts-and-bolts level.  If the two systems had identical order specs, but were in different orders, chances of a change like that are higher.  Maybe a long shot, but probably not a bad next-step before other troubleshooting.
